# Unable to Pass Valid JSON Between Lambda Functions

Tags: java, aws-lambda

I am having trouble passing valid JSON between two different Java AWS Lambda functions. The first function generates rawJson "String" that is formatted like this:

```
rawJson: [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "createdOn": 1535177185000,
    "text": "test text"
  }
]
```

This is passed to a second Lambda function:

```
request.withFunctionName(FUNCTION_NAME).withPayload(rawJson);
awsLambdaClient.invoke(request);
```

At the beginning of the second Lambda function, I print the value of the input Object:

```
inputObject: [{id=1, createdOn=1535177185000, text=test text}]
```

The quotes have been stripped and this is no longer valid JSON. Any attempt to map this back to my POJOs (or to even have my Lambda function accept a "String" like it should, instead of an "Object") results in a JSON-related exception.

Why is my valid JSON becoming malformed between the two Lambdas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was my fault. Like I mentioned, I had a RequestHandler like this:

```
RequestHandler<Object, Void>
```

That wasn't necessary. Lambda is smart enough on its own to serialize and deserialize my objects. Works fine with my code updated to:

```
RequestHandler<List<MyClass>, Void>
```